# Load markers dynamically

Tags: mongodb, react-native

I need to load markers in my map, but I want to load just those who are in the shown area of the app.
To do this I'd need the most northeast and the most southwest coordinates shown in the map. So I could find the markers using the $geoWithin and $box operator from MongoDB.

How I could get the map bounds? The coordinate more southwest and northeast of the shwon area of the map?

Answer (score 1):

==============UPDATE============

Here is the solution by `aforty` on github:

```js
<MapView onRegionChangeComplete={(center) => {
  let northeast = {
      latitude: center.latitude + center.latitudeDelta / 2,
      longitude: center.longitude + center.longitudeDelta / 2,
    }
    , southwest = {
      latitude: center.latitude - center.latitudeDelta / 2,
      longitude: center.longitude - center.longitudeDelta / 2,
    };

  console.log(center, northeast, southwest);
}} />
```

and here is the link to the issue:

https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/issues/356

==================================

You can specify `onRegionChange` and `onRegionChangeComplete` on the map. These functions are called when user drags the map and when the dragging is complete. You get a region object as an argument of the function, which is an object with `{latitude: 123, longitude: 123, latitudeDelta: 12, longitudeDelta: 12}`. You can use this to calculate the bounding box.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html#onregionchange

Comment: Aakash Sigdel. How can I use this longitudeDelta and latitudeDelta to get the bounds? I get this values but I'm not knowing how to work with them.